# Rendering View java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 0

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, servlet-filters

I have a problem when I try to login in my web application, the user is ok, because with the trace I can see when the HQL found the data, so to more visible the stack trace is in below:

For the application I use these libraries:

- Primefaces 3.5
- JSF 2.1.21
- Hibernate 4.0.10
- JPA 2.0
- Tomcat 7.0

  ```
  abr. 30, 2013 4:25:14 PM com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy handleRenderException
  SEVERE: Error Rendering View[/pages/protected/index.xhtml]
  java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 0
  at java.lang.String.charAt(Unknown Source)
  at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.getResourceURL(MultiViewHandler.java:332)
  at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.getResourceURL(CoreRenderer.java:76)
  at org.primefaces.renderkit.OutcomeTargetRenderer.getTargetURL(OutcomeTargetRenderer.java:91)
  at org.primefaces.component.menu.BaseMenuRenderer.encodeMenuItem(BaseMenuRenderer.java:78)
  at org.primefaces.component.tieredmenu.TieredMenuRenderer.encodeMenuContent(TieredMenuRenderer.java:104)
  at org.primefaces.component.tieredmenu.TieredMenuRenderer.encodeSubmenu(TieredMenuRenderer.java:166)
  at org.primefaces.component.tieredmenu.TieredMenuRenderer.encodeMenuContent(TieredMenuRenderer.java:123)
  at org.primefaces.component.tieredmenu.TieredMenuRenderer.encodeMenu(TieredMenuRenderer.java:77)
  at org.primefaces.component.menubar.MenubarRenderer.encodeMarkup(MenubarRenderer.java:52)
  at org.primefaces.component.menu.BaseMenuRenderer.encodeEnd(BaseMenuRenderer.java:39)
  at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:881)
  at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1786)
  at javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:168)
  at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:851)
  at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1779)
  at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1782)
  at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1782)
  at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:439)
  at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:124)
  at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120)
  at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
  at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
  at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:304)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
  at com.test.ems2.filter.LoginCheckFilter.doFilter(LoginCheckFilter.java:69)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:240)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:164)
  at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:462)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:164)
  at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
  at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:562)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
  at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:395)
  at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:250)
  at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:188)
  at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:302)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
  ```

web.xml file

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    <display-name>EMS2App</display-name>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name>
        <param-value>bluesky</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>/pages/protected/index.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Development</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>LoginCheckFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.test.ems2.filter.LoginCheckFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>loginActionURI</param-name>
            <param-value>/EMS2APP/pages/public/login.xhtml</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>LoginCheckFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>AdminPagesFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.test.ems2.filter.AdminPagesFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>AdminPagesFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/pages/protected/admin/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>DefaultUserPagesFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.test.ems2.filter.DefaultUserPagesFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>DefaultUserPagesFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/pages/protected/defaultUser/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

faces-config.xml file

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<faces-config xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
          http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_1.xsd"
    version="2.1">
    <application>
        <resource-bundle>
            <base-name>messages</base-name>
            <var>bundle</var>
        </resource-bundle>
        <message-bundle>messages</message-bundle>
    </application>
</faces-config>
```

My AbstractFilter class

```
public class AbstractFilter {

    public AbstractFilter() {
        super();
    }

    protected void doLogin(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, HttpServletRequest req) throws ServletException, IOException {
        RequestDispatcher rd = req.getRequestDispatcher("/pages/public/login.xhtml");
        rd.forward(request, response);
    }

    protected void accessDenied(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, HttpServletRequest req) throws ServletException, IOException {
        RequestDispatcher rd = req.getRequestDispatcher("/pages/public/accessDenied.xhtml");
        rd.forward(request, response);
    }
}
```

My LoginCheckFilter class:

```
public class LoginCheckFilter extends AbstractFilter implements Filter {
    private static List<String> allowedURIs;

    public void init(FilterConfig fConfig) throws ServletException {
        if(allowedURIs == null){
            allowedURIs = new ArrayList<String>();
            allowedURIs.add(fConfig.getInitParameter("loginActionURI"));
            allowedURIs.add("/EMS2App/javax.faces.resource/main.css.xhtml");
            allowedURIs.add("/EMS2App/javax.faces.resource/theme.css.xhtml");
            allowedURIs.add("/EMS2App/javax.faces.resource/primefaces.js.xhtml");
            allowedURIs.add("/EMS2App/javax.faces.resource/primefaces.css.xhtml");
            allowedURIs.add("/EMS2App/javax.faces.resource/jquery/jquery.js.xhtml");
            allowedURIs.add("/EMS2App/javax.faces.resource/messages/messages.png.xhtml");
            allowedURIs.add("/EMS2App/javax.faces.resource/images/ui-icons_2e83ff_256x240.png.xhtml");
            allowedURIs.add("/EMS2App/javax.faces.resource/images/ui-icons_38667f_256x240.png.xhtml");
        }
    }

    public void destroy() {
    }

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        HttpSession session = req.getSession();

        if (session.isNew()) {
            doLogin(request, response, req);
            return;
        }

        User user = (User) session.getAttribute("user");

        if (user == null && !allowedURIs.contains(req.getRequestURI())) {
            System.out.println(req.getRequestURI());
            doLogin(request, response, req);
            return;
        }

        chain.doFilter(request, response);  //error -> row 69
    }
}
```

The file: /pages/protected/index.xhtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets" xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui" >
<h:body>
    <ui:composition template="/pages/protected/templates/master.xhtml">
        <ui:define name="divMain">
            #{bundle.welcomeMessage} :<br/>
        </ui:define>    
    </ui:composition>
</h:body>
</html>
```

master.xhtml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">

<h:head>
    <title>EMS2</title>
    <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="main.css" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</h:head>

<h:body>
    <f:view contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" encoding="UTF-8" >
        <div id="divTop" style="vertical-align: middle;">
            <ui:insert name="divTop">
                <ui:include src="top.xhtml" />
            </ui:insert>
        </div>

        <div id="divMain">
            <p:growl id="messageGrowl" />
            <ui:insert name="divMain" />
        </div>

        <div id="divLeft">
            <ui:insert name="divDown">
                <ui:include src="down.xhtml" />
            </ui:insert>
        </div>

        <h:outputScript library="javascript" name="jscodes.js" />
    </f:view>
</h:body>
</html>
```

down.xhtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<h:body>
    <ui:composition>
        <h:form>
            <p>Test test test</p><br />         
        </h:form>
    </ui:composition>
</h:body>
</html>
```

top.xhtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
   <h:body>   
     <ui:composition>
        <div id="topMessage">
            <h1>
                <h:form>
                    <p:menubar>
                    <p:submenu label="Personnes">
                        <p:menuitem label="Ajouter Personne" url="#"/>
                        <p:menuitem label="Miss a jour Personne" url="#"/>
                    </p:submenu>
                    <p:submenu label="Absences">
                        <p:menuitem label="Poser des absences" url="#"/>
                        <p:menuitem label="Validation des absences" url="#"/>
                        <p:menuitem label="Gestion de absences" url="#"/>
                    </p:submenu>
                    <p:submenu label="Pointage">
                        <p:menuitem label="Saisie des temps" url="#"/>
                        <p:menuitem label="Validation des temps" url="#"/>
                        <p:menuitem label="Extration des temps Vers PowerMax" url="#"/>
                    </p:submenu>
                    <p:submenu label="Projet/Activite">
                        <p:submenu label="Activite">
                            <p:menuitem label="Creer Activite" url="/pages/protected/admin/dialogs/creerActivite.xhtml" />
                            <p:menuitem label="Miss a jour l'Activite" url="/pages/protected/admin/dialogs/missAJourActivite.xhtml" />
                        </p:submenu>
                        <p:submenu label="Projet">
                            <p:menuitem label="Creer projet" url="/pages/protected/admin/dialogs/creerProjet.xhtml" />
                            <p:menuitem label="Miss a jour projet" url="/pages/protected/admin/dialogs/missAJourProjet.xhtml" />
                        </p:submenu>
                    </p:submenu>
                    <p:submenu label="Rapport">
                        <p:menuitem label="Statistique projet" url="#"/>
                        <p:menuitem label="Statistique diverses" url="#"/>
                    </p:submenu>
                </p:menubar>
                #{bundle.loginWelcomeMessage}: #{userMB.user.name} | <p:commandButton value="#{bundle.logOut}" action="#{userMB.logOut()}" ajax="false" style="font-size: 20px;" />
                </h:form>
            </h1>
        </div>
     </ui:composition>   
   </h:body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think the error is comming from the xhtml (/pages/protected/index.xhtml), a primefaces menu... could we see this file?

Comment: @AlexandreLavoie Yes, I have added the file **index.xhtml** . Please see again the post.

Comment: Since the error looks like in an EL, maybe it comes from the template from index, are all the page using master.xhtml having this error? If yes, will need to take a look at it!

Comment: @AlexandreLavoie I have added all files **.xhtml**, see again. Thank you

Comment: The exception+stacktrace hints that you've somewhere a `<p:menuItem url="">` with empty string as URL. This is however not visible in the code provided so far. So either you're not running the code you think you're running (clean/rebuild/redeploy/restart), or there's more into the code. By the way, creating a fullworthy SSCCE in flavor of **only one** copy'n'paste'n'runnable XHTML file (and very maybe a managed bean) would tremendously help you (and us) in nailing down the cause instead of this code bomb of which the major part is irrelevant to the concrete problem.

Comment: @BalusC I found the problem, its work fine! Thank you!

Comment: What was the problem???? I have the same problem, please help me.